# How to detect if browser cookies are enabled in ASP.Net MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I've to detect in my ASP.Net MVC application if cookies are disabled in the client's browser. All my searches result in asp.net WebForms with Page_Load etc., instead of an ASP.Net MVC application.

How can I detect on the server side if browser cookies are enabled?

Comment: The only way to do that is to create and add a cookie yourself and redirect, then in the method you redirect to - `if (Request.Cookies["yourCookieName"] != null) { // they are enabled`

Answer (score 1):

Controller Code :

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var browser = Request.Browser;
            string s = "Browser Capabilities\n"
                       + "Type = " + browser.Type + "\n"
                       + "Name = " + browser.Browser + "\n"
                       + "Version = " + browser.Version + "\n"
                       + "Major Version = " + browser.MajorVersion + "\n"
                       + "Minor Version = " + browser.MinorVersion + "\n"
                       + "Platform = " + browser.Platform + "\n"
                       + "Is Beta = " + browser.Beta + "\n"
                       + "Is Crawler = " + browser.Crawler + "\n"
                       + "Is AOL = " + browser.AOL + "\n"
                       + "Is Win16 = " + browser.Win16 + "\n"
                       + "Is Win32 = " + browser.Win32 + "\n"
                       + "Supports Frames = " + browser.Frames + "\n"
                       + "Supports Tables = " + browser.Tables + "\n"
                       + "Supports Cookies = " + browser.Cookies + "\n"
                       + "Supports VBScript = " + browser.VBScript + "\n"
                       + "Supports JavaScript = " +
                       browser.EcmaScriptVersion.ToString() + "\n"
                       + "Supports Java Applets = " + browser.JavaApplets + "\n"
                       + "Supports ActiveX Controls = " + browser.ActiveXControls
                       + "\n"
                       + "Supports JavaScript Version = " +
                       browser["JavaScriptVersion"] + "\n";


            ViewBag.Message = s;
            return View();
        }
```

and you can use in view :

```
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code can be used in `asp.net MVC`

**Step 1: Create cookie if doesn't exist**

```
public ActionResult CreateCookie()
{

  //Check if cookie Enabled on Page Load
  if (Request.Cookies["UserInfo"] != null)
  {
    // Cookie is enabled 
    // TODO , write your code
  }           
  else
  {
    // Create a new cookie, if cookie is null

    HttpCookie userCookie = new HttpCookie("UserInfo");
    userCookie["Name"] = "example";
    userCookie["Company"] = "example";
    userCookie.Expires.AddDays(50); // cookie will expire after 50 days
    Response.Cookies.Add(userCookie);

    return RedirectToAction("CookieEnabled");

 }

   return View();
}
```

**Step 2: Check if cookie enabled**

```
public ActionResult CookieEnabled()
{
    if (Request.Cookies["UserInfo"] != null)
    {
        // Cookie is enabled 
        // TODO , write your code
    }

    else
    {
        // Cookie is disabled 
        // TODO , write your code
    }

    return View();
}
```

Note: You can also check this in client side using `JavaScript`, check [this](http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.in/2015/02/how-to-check-if-cookies-are-enabled.html) article.